# В Qt Designer исчезла левая панель, как вернуть её обратно

Tags: qt, qt-designer

[image: Слева должна быть панель, тут её нет]
С проблемой столкнулся вчера, в интернете инфы не нашел. Можно ли как нибудь, без переустановки программы, вернуть эту панель обратно?

Answer (score 1):

В верхней панели Вид -> Панель виджетов

Answer (score 0):

View -> Widget Box. Если учитывать англ. раскладку. Только что разобрался.